# Enable Button on DropDown Select in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the vuetify material library and i have a `v-select` with items assigned to it. How can i make so that only when an item in selected that the button will get enabled?

Here is a sample [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/LYEdaEz?editors=1010).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        'Foo', 'Bar', 'Biz', 'Buzz'
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout row class="ml-3">
      <v-flex xs4>
        <v-select label="Select Something" :items="items"></v-select>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs4 class="ml-3 mt-2">
        <v-btn disabled>Button</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

So by default the button will be disabled, only on a select from one of the options in the dropdown will the button be enabled. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your `v-select` to a variable, and then conditionally disable the button by checking the variable value, something like the following.

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/leopsidom/pen/bGNvZgP?editors=1010).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        'Foo', 'Bar', 'Biz', 'Buzz'
      ],
      selectedItem: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout row class="ml-3">
      <v-flex xs4>
        <v-select label="Select Something" :items="items" v-model="selectedItem"></v-select>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs4 class="ml-3 mt-2">
        <v-btn :disabled="selectedItem === null">Button</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```